# Using selenium in order to click on a date in fullcalendar scheduler

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, noraui

I'm using the Fullcalendar Resource-timeline feature.
[image]

I want to create automatic tests that click on dates in order to create events. The problem here, is that the cells are not dom elements. The solution I came up so far is to calculate the coordinates for the cursor to click, but it's not working.

```
    WebDriver driver = getDriver();
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

    // Get absence calendar
    WebElement absenceCalendar = getAbsenceCalendar(driver);

    // Get X coordinate for the first monday of the month. Add 5px in order to close in to the center
    int xCoordinates = getFirstDayFromAnyCalendar(absenceCalendar,"L").getLocation().getX()+5;

    logger.info("X: "+xCoordinates);
    // Get Y coordinate from jeune

    int yCoordinates = getJeuneLineFromCalendar(absenceCalendar,jeune).getLocation().getY();
    logger.info("Y: "+yCoordinates);

     //Move the cursor to the top left corner of the screen
    actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")), 0, 0);

    //Move the cursor to the coordinates and click.
    actions.moveByOffset(xCoordinates, yCoordinates).click().perform();
```

The coordinates checks out, but the click does not work. Any idea ?

[image]

Comment: even fullcalendar themselves don't seem to have an automated test for this - see https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/tree/master/packages/__tests__ . So I'd guess it's probably impossible. Maybe you should ask them how they test it currently. (And not sure you really need to their their core functionality all over again, do you?)

Comment: Thank you.Given the paid licence, we have an email support from them. I'll contact them and I'll let you know